# Record Sound from Directional Speakers

Tags: audio-recording, audio

How would I set up a microphone and laptop to record sound from a directional device like these ?

http://hypersound.com/hypersound_technology.php
http://www.soundlazer.com/
Audio Spotlight from Holosonics

I am about 35 to 45 metres from the device which is being used mainly at night to create a nuisance. 
The best microphone I have is a Samson CO1U.

Comment: Point microphone at speaker, hit record...  You, of course, need to be within the speaker's beam.  I'm not sure what the question is here as this seems exceptionally straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing special about a highly-directional speaker as far as miking it. As with any speaker, your mic needs to be somewhere in the speaker's projection cone, and the only major difference is that that cone is narrower.

As with miking any speaker, there will be (comparatively subtle) tonal differences depending on where you are within that cone, in the same ballpark as the differences you might expect from using different models of microphone. If your ears can hear something from that position, your mic should hear something as well.